# Как сделать анимацию в 2 векторах в unity2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не могу понять как сделать анимацию в векторах Horizontal и Vertical
Читал документацию от unity но там только один вектор, а как добавить второй не написано

Comment: Может быть, Вы добавите пример Ваего кода и ссылку на документацию? Так будет проще понять, о чем идет речь...

Comment: Он про `Blend Tree` что ли... Ну почему все гадалки свалили на `Red Bull Music Festival`.